# how to add/update execute shell commands for existing jenkins jobs using groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Actually i'm working on groovy script to add shell commands(for ex: echo "hello") to execute shell jenkins job configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for how to replace the shell for a job. pay attention that this is for jobs that have only one shell execution, since it will replace all shells with the new shell.

```
def jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()

def jobName = "yourJobName"
def job = jenkins.getItem(jobName)
def builders = job.getBuildersList()

hudson.tasks.Shell newShell = new hudson.tasks.Shell("echo \"new command\" ")
builders.replace(newShell)
```

Comment: thanks Tizki ko, i will add it to my code for testing.